# Ios browser get time with seconds

Tags: javascript, iphone, datetime, browser

I want to get user input. User browser my page on safari then they can select Hour, Minit, Seconds .. I want to get both value .. It work on Android phone
http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8BYt3/

`<input id="settime" type="time" step="1" />
document.getElementById("settime").value = "13:24:00";`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question is mildly confusing, are you trying to do this:

```
var date = new Date();
var hour = date.getHours();
var minutes = date.getMinutes();
var seconds = date.getSeconds();

document.getElementById("settime").value = hour + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
```

Comment: Nope, I want to get user input. User browser my page on safari then they can select Hour, Minit, Seconds .. I want to get both value .. It work on Android phone

Comment: Can you update your question to reflect this, and also add your code please.

Answer (score 0):

In 2022, this is still not possible on iOS Safari.

Have a look at https://caniuse.com/?search=input%20time

the `step` attribute, the one that triggers the seconds in a input `time`, is not supported yet.